# How do rx_bytes and tx_bytes increment in /sys/class/net

Tags: linux

The statistics available in `/sys/class/net/<if>/statistics` are, among others, the rx_bytes and tx_bytes, which correspond to received and transmitted packets in an interface.

Regarding the following topology, with 3 computers:

**A** (eth1) < ----- > (eth0) **B** (eth1)  <---------> (eth0) **C**

Where A is a client of the server C and B receives the client's traffic and forwards it to C, and from C to A. When traffic from A arrives to B eth0, supposedly, rx_bytes should increment. However, when the response from the server C reaches B eth0, does it also increments the rx_bytes?

My question is: do the rx_bytes increment for ingress and/or egress traffic? Maybe for traffic coming from all sources?

Comment: "when the response from the server C reaches B eth0, does it also increments the rx_bytes". No it doesn't. There are no packets received at B-eth0 in that case. There are only packets sent out B-eth0. The packets forwarded from B-eth1 to B-eth0 is not considered as received packets.